CSS couldn't be used inside Lightning Component
So I have been learning Lightning Component for a while and I know we have styling hooks to style lightning components like lightning-card, lightning-badge, etc. However, whenever I got, let say, a  inside a component, I couldn't style it using normal css. Something like this doesn't work
    <lightning-card>
    <div class = "abc">
    <span> test </span>
    </lightning-card>

and then the css file
    .abc {
    background-color: blue;
    }

doesn't work. I have 2 questions:

Why is this and how to style the normal components inside lightning component ?
For styling lightning components ( and normal component as well ), does every class has to be slds class to be styled by css ?

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Have you indeed managed to save the given LWC to the org? There's a closing </div> missing. As soon as you add this in, you will see some blue ;-) So the answer to your second question is: No, we don't need to use Lightning stylesheets throughout, and I haven't seen any Salesforce UI developer, who goes slds-only.

Hi, the above are just my examples, but I add the closing tag div and it still don't work. I think lightning doesn't allow styling inside lightning component unless I use dynamic styling

Maybe Build a Bear-Tracking App. It has some CSS in the section "Work with Lists of Records" :-)
